# How to debug a DLL project using QtCreator?

Tags: c++, c, qt, dll, qt-creator

I have written a non-Qt C DLL compiled with mingw using the QtCreator IDE.

When I inject the DLL into a process, the DLL causes that process to crash at a certain line of code. I found this line to be the culprit through the use of `OutputDebugString`. I know how to fix the line and the DLL works when that line is modified. However, for the purpose of learning how to use a debugger, I have left the line broken and unmodified.

How would I use the QtCreator debugger to find that same exact line is causing the problem? When QtCreator is set to compile in debug mode, pressing F5 results in the following dialog because there is no EXE:

[image]

Comment: Write a small program linking against the library that reproduces the problem and run that in the debugger. Or what do you mean exactly with "inject"?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection It is a low-level DLL file that edits the victim procces's memory. I can't link against the library because of how DLL injection works. Why am I editing another process's memory? I am editing the memory of an open-source project called Assault Cube. The purpose is to explore and learn more about how C code is translated into ASM and how computers work at the lower-level.

Comment: Well, you can just type executable name, that uses your dll and arguments to it in the window above and QtCreator will do the rest for you.

Comment: @Lol4t0: Oh that works too. Saves me a bit of time. Thanks

Comment: @Lol4t0: Actually, your method is even better. It lets me step through the code whereas I don't think I could do that with Nazar554's method.

Comment: @user2924308, it actually nearly the same assuming you opened the project you want to debug. Main difference is that Nazar554's method attaches debugger to already running application and my method will start application for you. Sometimes it's more convenient to attach, sometimes is to start. Both allow to step through the code if you built debug build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to run the debugger attached to the executable before injecting the DLL. The DLL must be built in debug configuration and its project needs to be opened. Attach the debugger using instructions [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#launching-in-attach-mode) and inject the DLL. If executable crashes you should see the stack trace and your DLL code when you click on selected stack frame. But be careful: if you corrupted the memory of the process the stack trace might be incomplete or incorrect.

Comment: Awesome! I was almost certain that this wasn't possible.

Comment: @user2924308 If you find my answer helpful, please accept it.